# Setup & configure NestJS 9 (TypeORM 0.3+) to use custom repositories

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm, repository-pattern, nestjs-config

I am currently attempting to update my project to the latest version of NestJS and TypeORM and I am having a great deal of difficulty wrapping my head around how to setup the project so that I can use custom repositories in a similar way that it was before.

The biggest problem is that `@EntityRepository` and `.getCustomRepository` have been deprecated. I have been pouring over documentation and I can't seem to figure out the new way of doing things.

From the TypeORM docs, it says to do something like this:

```
export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
    findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        return this.createQueryBuilder("user")
            .where("user.firstName = :firstName", { firstName })
            .andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName", { lastName })
            .getMany()
    },
})
```

ok... I get that... use the dataSource to create the repo and extend it with the additional functions. Seem's easy enough, right?

WRONG!

You can't create the repo until the dataSource object is created. In straight up TypeORM  you can create your `new DataSource` but in nest, it's an async bootstrap... which means when you import your repo/service files the data source isn't yet there.

grrr.

So, here is my code (simplified).
Basically, it's a small app with users. The users have a role. So you can get the user by name, or update the user name so long as it has a role. If the role is null, then you can't do it. (the create method is not included, assume it's there)

**app.config.ts**

```
// database values and such are loaded from an env file. (not included)
export const applicationModuleConfig: ApplicationModuleConfig = {
  typeOrmConfig: {
    type: "postgres",
    host,
    username,
    database,
    port,
    synchronize: false,
    cache: true,
    entities: [resolve(__dirname, "./**/*.entity.ts"), resolve(__dirname, "./**/*.entity.js")],
    migrations: [resolve(__dirname, "./migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}")],
    migrationsTableName: "migrations",
    migrationsRun: true,
    password,
  }
}
```

**users.entity.ts** (trimmed, assume there are more fields/columns)

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType("Users")
export class Users {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false, default: "" })
  name: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false, default: "" })
  role: string;
}
```

**users.repository.ts**

```
export const UsersRepository = dataSource.getRepository(Users).extend({
  findByName(name: string) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder("users")
      .where("users.name = :name", { name })
      .getOne()
  },
  async verifyRole(id: number) {
    const user = await this.createQueryBuilder("users")
      .where("users.id = :id", { id })
      .getOne()
    return user?.role !== null;
  },

})
```

**users.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private readOnly usersRepo: UsersRepository) {}

  findByName(name: string) {
    return this.usersRepo.findByName(name);
  }

  verifyRole(id: number) {
    return this.usersRepo.verifyRole(id);
  }
}
```

**users.resolver.ts**

```
@Resolver(() => User)
@UseGuards(GraphqlAuthGuard, PermissionsGuard, ScopeGuard)
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Query(() => User, { name: "user" })
  async getUser(
    @Args({
      name: "name",
      type: () => String,
    })
    name: string,
    @CurrentUser() currentUser: AuthorizedUser,
  ): Promise<Users> {
    return this.usersService.findByName(name);
  }

  // assume EditUsersInput is a object matching the entity fields.
  @Mutation(() => Users)
  @VerifyUser<{ input: EditUsersInput }>(({ input }) => {
    // >>> this doesn't work <<<*
    return UsersRepository.verifyRole(input.id);
  })
  async editUser(
    @Args(
      {
        name: "input",
        type: () => EditUsersInput,
      },
      new ValidationPipe(),
    )
    input: EditUsersInput,
  ): Promise<Users> {
    await UsersRepository.editUser(input); // assume the editUser method exists in the service and repo.
    return UsersRepository.findByUserId(input.id); // assume the findByUserId method exists in the service and repo.
  }
```

**app.module.ts** *(I will admit I am not sure what I am supposed to be doing in this file)*

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([...entitiesWithoutAModuleHere])],
  providers: [UsersService, UsersRepository],
  exports: [UsersService, UsersRepository],
})
export class ApplicationModule {
  static forRoot(config: ApplicationModuleConfig): DynamicModule {
    const {
      graphql,
      typeOrmConfig,
      numConcurrentReportJobs,
      redis: { tls: redisTls, ...redisRest },
    } = config;

    ////
    // a bunch of redis code goes in here...
    ////

    return {
      module: ApplicationModule,
      imports: [
        // omitted unrelated imports, such as bullQueue and stuff like that.
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          ...typeOrmConfig,
        }),
        GraphQLModule.forRoot(graphql),
        ConfigurationModule.forRoot(config), // I am not sure if this file is important or not, but I am omitting it for now.
      ],
    };
  }

  constructor(public dataSource: DataSource) {
     // AH HA! The dataSource has been initialized by nest!
     // but, the repository errors have already occurred and it never got this far.
     // I don't know what to do here.
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import blah from "blah";
import { applicationModuleConfig } from "./app.config";
import everythingElse from "otherStuff";
import { ApplicationModule } from "./app.module";   //  <-- KaBOOM!

async function bootstrap() {
  initializeTransactionalContext();
  patchTypeORMRepositoryWithBaseRepository();

  const ApplicationModule = require("./app.module");
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule.forRoot(applicationModuleConfig), { bodyParser: false });

  app.use(
    session({
      resave: false, //As per https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new (require("connect-pg-simple")(session))({
        createTableIfMissing: true,
      }),
      secret: process.env.APP_SESSION_SECRET, cookie: { secure: secureCookies },
    }),
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap().then(() => null);
```

I know I am doing it wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it right. Any thoughts, comments, suggestions, examples, tutorials, or explanations of the right way?

Thanks!